# two tinymce editor issue in firefox

Tags: tinymce

i am using two same tinymce editor in same page. the first editor is editable and the second editor is not editable in firefox.all other browser both editor is editable.Is any solution available for this?

this is my code

```
> <textarea id="recipeDesc" class="mceEditor required" cols="80"
> rows="24" title=" Enter a Description " helper="formTinyMce"
> name="recipeDesc" style="display: none;"></textarea> <span
> id="recipeDesc_container" class="mceEditor o2k7SimpleSkin"> <table
> class="mceLayout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 500px;
> height: 450px;"> <tbody> <tr> <td> <div class="mceIframeContainer">
> <iframe id="recipeDesc_ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:"""
> style="width: 100%; height: 430px;"> <html> </iframe> </div> </td>
> </tr> <tr class="last"> </tbody> </table> </span> <br> <label
> for="recipeProcess">Recipe Process : </label> <textarea
> id="recipeProcess" class="mceEditor required" cols="80" rows="24"
> title=" Enter a process " helper="formTinyMce" name="recipeProcess"
> style="display: none;"></textarea> <span id="recipeProcess_container"
> class="mceEditor o2k7SimpleSkin"> <table class="mceLayout"
> cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 500px; height: 450px;">
> <tbody> <tr> <td> <div class="mceIframeContainer"> <iframe
> id="recipeProcess_ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:"""
> style="width: 100%; height: 430px;"> <html> <head
> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <body id="tinymce"
> class="mceContentBody " spellcheck="false" dir="ltr"> <false> </body>
> </html> </iframe> </div> </td> </tr> <tr class="last"> </tbody>
> </table> </span>
```

Comment: how this related to zend framework?

Comment: can you show us your tinymce configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a bug with Firefox which is resolved if you install the latest nightly build: http://nightly.mozilla.org/.  Usual warnings apply when using a nightly - it might not be stable!

Comment: I believe this is now fixed with Firefox 12.